# Erro no ValidationResult ao tentar criar o Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Sigma.Infra.Data.Context.ValidationResult: : EntityType 'ValidationResult' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Sigma.Infra.Data.Context.ValidationFailure: : EntityType 'ValidationFailure' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ValidationResult: EntityType: EntitySet 'ValidationResult' is based on type 'ValidationResult' that has no keys defined.
ValidationFailures: EntityType: EntitySet 'ValidationFailures' is based on type 'ValidationFailure' that has no keys defined.
```

Classe onde está o ValidationResult, mas não pode ser alterada

```
 #region Assembly FluentValidation, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0
 // 
  #endregion


 using FluentValidation.Results;

 using System.Collections.Generic;


  
  namespace FluentValidation.Results
  {

    // Summary:
    //     The result of running a validator
    public class ValidationResult
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new validationResult
        public ValidationResult();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new ValidationResult from a collection of failures
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   failures:
        //     List of FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure which is later available through
        //     FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult.Errors. This list get's copied.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     Every caller is responsible for not adding null to the list.
        public ValidationResult(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> failures);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Whether validation succeeded
        public virtual bool IsValid { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A collection of errors
        public IList<ValidationFailure> Errors { get; }
        public string[] RuleSetsExecuted { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Generates a string representation of the error messages separated by new lines.
        public override string ToString();
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Generates a string representation of the error messages separated by the specified
        //     character.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   separator:
        //     The character to separate the error messages.
        public string ToString(string separator);
    }
}
```

Classe do ISelfValidation

```
using FluentValidation.Results;

namespace Sigma.Domain.Interfaces{

    /// <summary>
    /// Api de validação
    /// https://fluentvalidation.net
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public interface ISelfValidation
    {
    
        ValidationResult GetValidationResult();
    
        bool IsValid { get; }
    }
    
}
```

Essa é a entidade e o método que aparece no erro está dentro do ISelfValidation

```
public class ParametroArea : ISelfValidation
{

    public ParametroArea(){

        objID=Guid.NewGuid();

    }
    public Guid objID { get; set; }

    public Guid IDAreaServico { get; set; }

    public Guid IDUltimaCultura { get; set; }

    public string areaArrendada { get; set; }

    public string tempoRestante { get; set; }

    public string condicaoAtual { get; set; }

    public string observacaoComplementar { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual AreaServico AreaServico { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Cultura Cultura { get; set; }

        private ValidationResult validationResult;
        public ValidationResult GetValidationResult()
        {
            return validationResult;
        }

        private void SetValidationResult(ValidationResult value)
        {
            validationResult = value;
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                var validador = new ParametroAreaValidation();

                this.SetValidationResult(validador.Validate(this));
                return GetValidationResult().IsValid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E a entidade`ValidationResult` possui uma chave primária?

Comment: Consegue colocar o código de sua entidade ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não, ela não possui chave primaria

Comment: @Matheus consigo sim

Answer (score 1):

1º - tenta colocar dessa forma:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
public Guid objID { get; set; }
```

2º - Retire o contructor que gera o Guid:

```
public ParametroArea(){

    objID=Guid.NewGuid();

}
```

Comment: O Erro continua, quando eu coloco o [Key] o Validation pede uma annotations e o ISelfValidations pede para implementar uma interface

Comment: @Jcsmz, sim você precisa referenciar o pacote DataAnnotations

Comment: Sim, eu fiz mesmo assim o erro persistiu

Comment: Em que momento exatamente esse erro acontece ?

Comment: Quando eu vou executar o migration, add-migration parametro

Comment: É estranho, pois setando o [Key] deveria funcionar, tenta fazer essas duas alterações que postei na minha pergunta